# Issues Deserializing Xml in C#

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I'm following the tutorial given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows) for deserializing an embedded xml document.

My Xml doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ArrayOfAgency xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DbAgencyDefinition>
    <Name>RTD</Name>
    <Country>USA</Country>
    <City>Denver</City>
    <State>CO</State>
    <GtfsZipUrlDirectory>http://www.address.com/etc/</GtfsZipUrlDirectory>
    <GtfsZipUrlFileName>file_name.zip</GtfsZipUrlFileName>
  </DbAgencyDefinition>
</ArrayOfAgency>
```

My class I'm deserializing to:

```
public class DbAgencyDefinition
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string GtfsZipUrlDirectory { get; set; }
        public string GtfsZipUrlFileName { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }
```

The code that's trying to deserialize the XML to a list of DbAgencyDefinition:

```
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(DbAgencyDefinition)).Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.Resources.xml.AgencyDefinitions.xml");
            var agencies = new List<DbAgencyDefinition>();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DbAgencyDefinition>));
                agencies = (List<DbAgencyDefinition>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
System.Exception: There is an error in XML document. <ArrayOfAgency xmlns=''> was not expected
```

I've tried a million things with the XML, marking the class as Serializable, and it always returns this error. I looked at the code samples that the tutorial gives and I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS for Windows, and maybe on Mac as well, has a special tool that will convert copied Xml into autogenerated classes. Now, it's not perfect but if you take your Xml file it generates a couple of classes similar to this:

```
public class ArrayOfAgency
{
    public ArrayOfAgencyDbAgencyDefinition DbAgencyDefinition { get; set; }
}

public class ArrayOfAgencyDbAgencyDefinition
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string GtfsZipUrlDirectory { get; set; }
    public string GtfsZipUrlFileName { get; set; }
}
```

As you might notice `ArrayOfAgency` is determined as a class holding a `DbAgencyDefinition`, which is why it's throwing an error while trying to deserialize it directly into a `List<DbAgencyDefinition>`. The type and what the serializer is expecting are not quite the same.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfAgency));
var agencies = ((ArrayOfAgency)serializer.Deserialize(reader)).DbAgencyDefinition;
```

Also, as I mentioned the auto-generation may not be perfect because `ArrayOfAgency` may need to hold an array instead of a direct class if there can be more than one `DbAgencyDefinition` possible in Xml.

```
public class ArrayOfAgency
{
    public ArrayOfAgencyDbAgencyDefinition[] DbAgencyDefinition { get; set; }
}
```

If you need more help or info on Xml Serialization check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization).

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication120
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfAgency));
                ArrayOfAgency agencies = (ArrayOfAgency)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }

        }
    }
    public class ArrayOfAgency
    {
        public DbAgencyDefinition DbAgencyDefinition { get; set; }
    }
    public class DbAgencyDefinition
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string GtfsZipUrlDirectory { get; set; }
        public string GtfsZipUrlFileName { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain your proposed solution in comparison to OP's code?

Comment: This is helping, but suppose there are multiple DbAgencyDefinition nodes in the XML? Should ArrayOfAgency class have public List<DbAgencyDefinition> instead? I tried that and it's not erroring, but not returning anything either.

Comment: With multiple DbAgencyDefinition nodes, simply change the return type of the property to an array.

public DbAgencyDefinition[] DbAgencyDefinition { get; set; }  I recommend choosing a different name though, that's just confusing.

Comment: A array at the root level of xml is consider not well formed.  The Net serialization method will give an exception.  To handle an array at the root level you need to manually deserialize using XmlReader with the option set fragments.